# Solving the equation $\int_0^t \frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}dx=1+t+t^2$ by Laplace transform: Why does convolution work, but not my method?

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

**Question:**

> Solve  the equation $\int_0^t \frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}dx=1+t+t^2$

**My try:**

I applied Laplace transform to both sides of the equation.

$L\{\int_0^t \frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}dx\} = \frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{2}{s^3}$

The problem is about $L\{\int_0^t \frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}dx\} $.  We know that $L\{\int_0^tf(x)dx\}=\frac{1}{s}L\{f(t)\}$. So, we have:

$L\{\int_0^t \frac{y(x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}dx\} =\frac{1}{s}L\{\frac{y(t)}{\sqrt{t-t}}\}=\frac{1}{s}L\{\frac{y(t)}{\sqrt{0}}\}$

As you see, I get $\sqrt{0}$ as a part of the solution!

What's wrong? How should I fix this?

**Edit**: I know the convolution works for this equation. But the other way (the formula I mentioned above) should work too! doesn't it? What is wrong with my way?

Comment: Hint: that integral is a convolution of two functions. There is a formula for the Laplace transform of a convolution.

Comment: @User8128 Apparently, it turns out that the OP actually knew this, but was just wondering why the method above does not seem to work, or if it should, then how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$L\{ \int_0^t y(x) (t-x)^{-1/2}dx\} = L\{y(t)\} \times L\{t^{-1/2} \} = Y(s) \times \frac{\Gamma(-1/2)}{s^{1/2}}$

Comment: This answers the question *"How should I fix this?"*, however the question *"What's wrong?"* still stands.

Comment: @projectilemotion Great point! Actually, I know how to solve this problem with convolution... But the mystery is "why doesn't the other way work out?"

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh Indeed, you raise an interesting question. To avoid misinterpretation, I would strongly recommend that you emphasize in your post that you know how to solve the problem with convolution (The method used in this answer), but don't understand why the other way doesn't work.

Comment: @projectilemotion You're right ... I made an edit :)

Comment: I think that the problem arises because the function $1/\sqrt{t}$ has a discontinuity of the second kind at 0.